# Associate Office 365 AD Tenant with AZURE AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an office 365 Subscription that was created when i created my Dynamics 365 (CRM) trial version.
I also have a MSDN Enterprise Azure Subscription.
I'm trying to associate the office AZURE AD with my MSDN AZURE Subscription.

I'm trying to proceed as described in the below link
https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/billing-add-office-365-tenant-to-azure-subscription.md

But the link for the old azure management portal and  I'm not able to find a way to add "New Directory" with the option to choose "Existing Directory"

Awaiting your valuable inputs.

Regards,
Clement

Answer (score 0):

You can refer 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-use-existing-office-365-account-azure-subscription
 to know How to Associate or add Azure Subscription to Azure Active Directory. This should do the trick if you do not have any resources in the Azure Subscription that are dependent on the current tenant for the subscription.

So, what happens is that if you have anything on the current tenant for the Azure Subscription, that would be replicated to the tenant for the O365. All of the same would need to be re-created manually.

Only the Subscription Admin of the Azure Subscription would retain the access to the subscription.

If you should have resources and the access levels might be a question for you by the re-association of the Subscription to the O365 tenant, we would suggest you create a [Billing & Subscription Ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) so that Microsoft support team could personally assist you in the entire process effectively.